# Save 2 variables from an array to .csv

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, coordinates

I have 2 coordinate variables lon and lat

```
(array([-50.940605, -37.424145, -41.501717, -37.98916 , -60.632664,
       -38.158283, -58.0372  , -39.06596 , -60.815792, -49.303684,
       -38.46074 , -50.979015, -38.479317, -58.656593, -38.40213 ,
       -38.007423, -43.785126, -57.75844 , -42.781937, -74.90217 ,
       -34.498913, -49.227158, -96.485504, -72.128716, -39.414085],
      dtype=float32), array([-15.90009   , -15.913551  , -15.7658    , -16.47591   ,
        -4.1940403 , -14.563205  ,  -6.032389  , -14.852597  ,
        -4.24735   ,  15.848547  , -14.71412   , -17.052591  ,
       -14.079368  ,  -5.9365387 , -14.50551   , -16.48979   ,
       -16.616753  ,  -0.23096395, -15.882113  ,  -5.0795455],
      dtype=float32))
```

I want to short them and save as a .csv file like this:

```
-50.940605,-15.90009
-37.424145,-15.913551 
 -41.501717-15.7658 
 -37.98916,-16.47591
 -60.632664-4.1940403 
 -38.158283-14.563205
.... and so on
```

I'm using the commands

```
coord_file = (flag_lon.data[0:100], flag_lat.data[0:100]) # they are variables extracted from a NetCDF fila

np.savetxt('coord_file.csv', coord_file, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
 
print(open("coord_file.csv").read())
```

But it returns:

```
-50.940605,-37.424145,-41.501717,-37.98916,-60.632664,-38.158283,-58.0372,-39.06596,-60.815792,-49.303684,-38.46074,-50.979015,-38.479317,-58.656593,-38.40213,-38.007423,-43.785126
-15.90009,-15.913551,-15.7658,-16.47591,-4.1940403,-14.563205,-6.032389,-14.852597,-4.24735,15.848547,-14.71412,-17.052591,-14.079368,-5.9365387,-14.50551,-16.48979,-16.616753,-0.23096395,-15.882113,-5.0795455,-20.313402,15.771035,-7.3693175,-7.8538485,-14.27069,-16.976015,
```

How can I arrange them so that they are as pair lon,lat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
import numpy as np

lon = np.array([-50.940605, -37.424145, -41.501717, -37.98916, -60.632664])
lat = np.array([-15.90009, -15.913551, -15.7658, -16.47591, -4.1940403])
coords = np.column_stack((lon, lat))
np.savetxt('coordinates.csv', coords, delimiter=',', fmt='%.6f')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurred because the longitude and latitude arrays have different lengths: the longitude array has 25 elements, while the latitude array has only 20. To create a valid CSV file with pairs of coordinates, both arrays must have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider working with pandas and numpy.

numpy is a library designed for handling arrays and matrices and pandas is designed for data analysis and manipulation

As Marcin Orlowski already said both arrays need to have the same length.

Then you could use something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lon = np.array([value1, value2,..., value_x])
lat = np.array([value1, value2,..., value_x])

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'lon': lon, 'lat': lat})

#Save CSV
df.to_csv('coord_file.csv', index=False)
```

Thats how i would to it, hope this helped.